# fql query fails - suspected auth issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

In a page, if I make a test fql query it works:

```
$fql = 'SELECT name from user where uid = ' . $user_id;
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $fql,
                                 ));

        echo '<pre>Name: ' . $ret_obj[0]['name'] . '</pre>';
```

However if I try to run this query, it fails:

```
$fql2 = 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND sex =male';
$ret_obj2 = $facebook->api(array(
                           'method' => 'fql.query',
                           'query' => $fql2,
                         ));


echo '<pre>Name: ' . $ret_obj2[0]['name'] . '</pre>';
```

I suspect it is an auth problem, because the same fql query works in the graph api test tool!

If you want to checkout the full php code, it's the second example on this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Comment: What is $ret_obj2 set to when you "suspect" an auth problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support guys, the query wasn't working for 2 reasons:

1) I forgot the ; after the end of statement

2) In my code I used

```
`SELECT uid, name, pic_square, FROM`
```

instead of

```
`SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just basic permissions for this query, so this is not the issue. Try adding double quotes around "male":

`$fql2 = 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND sex="male"'`;